# Challenge-response auth for ble device

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem with security of my system. I have develop a mobile app that communicate with my Bluetooth Low Energy device. My device requires challenge-response authorization, it stored secret key, and it has not the Internet access. The question is how can I store that secret key safely in my cloud database? All my users need to use the same secret key to communicate with that device.

Comment: Please provide more information of the use case. How are the users going to use the key? Will they be able to see it? Can you only use symmetric key encryption, or is it possible to switch to public key?

Comment: The users receive an invitation to my system. Each invitation includes a list of devices that can be communicated with. The users are not able to see any credentials in my app. They don't know anything about authorization, just can click "connect" and then control that device. That's it. I'm afraid of storing plaintext password for each device.

Comment: The best solution seems to be using a simple PKI. Each user will have their own keys to connect to the devices, signed by some authority (probably yourself), and they will be able to revoke or generate new keys. However it is not a simple task and cannot be answered without knowing the threat model and many other parameters specific to your system. StackOverflow might not be the best place for such questions. Here more on PKI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about security without involving programming. The security sister site would be a good place to ask, but I'm afraid this would be put on hold there as well because it would be too broad / and would receive opinionated answers.